# Error checking external CA condition for ca certificate authority

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

Not sure how to solve the problem with the certificates, maybe someone has encountered this problem?

kernel

```
uname -a
Linux node2 3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Aug 25 17:23:54 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

OS

```
 cat /etc/os-release
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
```

kubectl

```
kubectl version

Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.2", GitCommit:"f5743093fd1c663cb0cbc89748f730662345d44d", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-09-16T13:41:02Z", GoVersion:"go1.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2023-03-31T09:11:37+03:00 is after 2023-03-25T05:32:30Z
```

kubeadm

```
kubeadm version
kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.2", GitCommit:"f5743093fd1c663cb0cbc89748f730662345d44d", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-09-16T13:38:53Z", GoVersion:"go1.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Problem:
```

When I try to get nodes:

```
 kubectl get nodes
Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2023-03-31T09:15:30+03:00 is after 2023-03-25T05:32:30Z
```

Trying to renew:

```
kubeadm alpha certs renew all
W0331 09:15:52.880115    4475 configset.go:348] WARNING: kubeadm cannot validate component configs for API groups [kubelet.config.k8s.io kubeproxy.config.k8s.io]
MISSING! certificate embedded in the kubeconfig file for the admin to use and for kubeadm itself
Error checking external CA condition for ca certificate authority: failure loading certificate for API server: failed to load certificate: the certificate has expired
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

Kubeam renew:

```
kubeadm alpha phase certs apiserver --apiserver-advertise-add                                                                               ress 10.2.27.11
unknown flag: --apiserver-advertise-address
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
[root@node2 pki]#
[root@node2 pki]#
[root@node2 pki]# kubeadm alpha phase certs apiserver --apiserver-advertise-addr                                                                               ess 10.2.27.11
unknown flag: --apiserver-advertise-address
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
[root@node2 pki]# sudo kubeadm alpha certs renew apiserver
sudo: kubeadm: command not found
[root@node2 pki]# kubeadm alpha certs renew apiserver
[renew] Reading configuration from the cluster...
[renew] FYI: You can look at this config file with 'kubectl -n kube-system get c                                                                               m kubeadm-config -oyaml'
[renew] Error reading configuration from the Cluster. Falling back to default co                                                                               nfiguration

W0404 13:54:08.589075   17136 configset.go:348] WARNING: kubeadm cannot validate                                                                                component configs for API groups [kubelet.config.k8s.io kubeproxy.config.k8s.io                                                                               ]
MISSING! certificate for serving the Kubernetes API

kubeadm alpha certs renew apiserver
[renew] Reading configuration from the cluster...
[renew] FYI: You can look at this config file with 'kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -oyaml'
[renew] Error reading configuration from the Cluster. Falling back to default configuration

W0404 13:54:26.555686   17270 configset.go:348] WARNING: kubeadm cannot validate component configs for API groups [kubelet.config.k8s.io kubeproxy.config.k8s.io]
MISSING! certificate for serving the Kubernetes API
[root@node2 pki]# kubeadm alpha certs renew apiserver-etcd-client
[renew] Reading configuration from the cluster...
[renew] FYI: You can look at this config file with 'kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -oyaml'
[renew] Error reading configuration from the Cluster. Falling back to default configuration

W0404 13:54:32.885559   17375 configset.go:348] WARNING: kubeadm cannot validate component configs for API groups [kubelet.config.k8s.io kubeproxy.config.k8s.io]
MISSING! certificate the apiserver uses to access etcd
[root@node2 pki]# kubeadm alpha certs renew apiserver-kubelet-client
[renew] Reading configuration from the cluster...
[renew] FYI: You can look at this config file with 'kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -oyaml'
[renew] Error reading configuration from the Cluster. Falling back to default configuration

W0404 13:54:37.895333   17459 configset.go:348] WARNING: kubeadm cannot validate component configs for API groups [kubelet.config.k8s.io kubeproxy.config.k8s.io]
MISSING! certificate for the API server to connect to kubelet
```

Answer (score 1):

This error Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid  indicates that on the DX APM OnPrem installation, the Kubernetes system creates its own key/certificate, and the validity is 1 year and then expires.

**Resolution**:

Try the resolution steps in this [doc](https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/232550/kubectl-unable-to-connect-to-the-server.html).

As mentioned in this [git link](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/581) you need to follow below steps:

1)Renew expired certificates, use kubeadm.

```
sudo kubeadm alpha certs renew apiserver

sudo kubeadm alpha certs renew apiserver-etcd-client

sudo kubeadm alpha certs renew apiserver-kubelet-client

sudo kubeadm alpha certs renew front-proxy-client
```

2)Generate new kube-configs

```
sudo kubeadm alpha kubeconfig user --org system:masters --client-name kubernetes-admin  > admin.conf

sudo kubeadm alpha kubeconfig user --client-name system:kube-controller-manager > controller-manager.conf

sudo kubeadm alpha kubeconfig user --org system:nodes --client-name system:node:$(hostname) > kubelet.conf

sudo kubeadm alpha kubeconfig user --client-name system:kube-scheduler > scheduler.conf
```

3)Move the newly generated Kube-configs to replace the existing kube configs.

```
sudo mv admin.conf /etc/kubernetes/

sudo mv controller-manager.conf /etc/kubernetes/

sudo mv kubelet.conf /etc/kubernetes/

sudo mv scheduler.conf /etc/kubernet
```

4)Restart the master components.

```
sudo kill -s SIGHUP $(pidof kube-apiserver)

sudo kill -s SIGHUP $(pidof kube-controller-manager)

sudo kill -s SIGHUP $(pidof kube-scheduler
```

Refer this official [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-certs/) for more information about Certificate Management with kubeadm.

Comment: at the end of my post the output of kubeadm alpha certs renew all with an error

Comment: @cryptoparty Please check my edited Answer

Comment: Error even on first step

Comment: run this command `mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config` and let me know if this work.

Comment: Error reading configuration from the Cluster. Falling back to default configuration

W0404 16:26:33.714086   27778 configset.go:348] WARNING: kubeadm cannot validate component configs for API groups [kubelet.config.k8s.io kubeproxy.config.k8s.io]
MISSING! certificate for serving the Kubernetes API

Comment: Now its ok! thx You, Do I need to do the same on another master nodes?